# Is this a bug in primefaces autocomplete?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to put an autocomplete that fetches suggestions as a list of `Entry<String, Integer>`

> ```
> <p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{suggester.suggestTopics}"
>             var="x1" itemLabel="#{x1.key}" itemValue="#{x1.value.toString()}" 
>             value="#{topicController.selected}"   />
> ```

Manged bean code is as follows:

> ```
> private int selected;
>
> public int getSelected() {
>     return selected;
> }
>
> public void setSelected(int selected) {
>     this.selected= selected;
> }
> ```

But this fails saying the Integer class doesn't have method/property named `key`. If I remove the `value` attribute from autocomplete then it starts working properly. But when I put value attribute it starts expecting that the object inside `var` should be of the same type as that inside `value` attribute. I believe/expect it should be that the object inside `itemValue` should be of the same type as that inside `value` attribute.

**I want to use POJOs for suggestions but pass just the entity Id to the value**

---

Using :
Primefaces 3.1
JSF 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

> I believe/expect it should be that the object inside itemValue should
>   be of the same type as that inside value attribute.

Yes this makes sense, and it is the same in the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf):

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1}" 
                id="basicPojo" 
                completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completePlayer}"  
                var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}" itemValue="#{p}" 
                converter="player" forceSelection="true"/>
```

As you see is `var="p"` and `itemValue="#{p}` where p is an instance of `Player`. And `selectedPlayer1` is also an instance of `Player`.

I don't know if it works with a Map since the Primefaces example is called "Pojo support" and the suggestions should be a `List` of elements of the same type as in the `value` attribute.

Comment: thanks Matt, but I don't much like this approach when I need to pass to DB just the id of selected player, this requires me to again fetch data from DB, rebuild the player object & use converters which could be otherwise just done by passing the playerId...

Comment: I want to use POJOs for suggestions but pass just the entity Id to the value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [Simple auto complete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) , but instead you looked at the wrong example on the showcase of the [Pojo Support](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf)

x1 refers to the int selected - while it expect to be referred to a POJO  (with key and value properties.) , that's why you get the message

> Integer class doesn't have method/property named key

Or simple use the [Simple auto complete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf)

Comment: I want to use POJOs for suggestions but pass just the entity Id to the value

Comment: why don't you pass the object and make use of it id attribute ?

Comment: I don't much like this approach since this requires me to again fetch data from DB, rebuild the object & use converters which could be otherwise just be avoided by passing the entityId..

Answer (score 0):

As commented to Matt you dont need to rebuild Player(Pojo) from Db. You can set simply id property of Player(Pojo) and in action method may be utilize this id to fetch it from DB.

In your case in convertor you might do

```
Entry<String, Integer> e = new Entry<String, Integer>();
e.setId(value)  // where value is passed in to convertor in method getAsObject.....
```

This value will be set to  `private Entry<String, Integer> selected`

I have used Pojo autocomplete but not tried with generic classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is outdated but I've had the same problem.
The point is that you have to assign var to p (var="p"). I think it's terribly unobvious (documentation doesnot mention it has to be that way) 'cause I thought I can assign any var name I want.