# Primefaces autocomplete using a list POJO and a String as default value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

i'm trying to use the primefaces autoComplete component with POJO.
I know i need a converter. I've successfully used it many time before. But this time i've a special requirement.
I need the POJO only to show many columns to the user, but when it's selected i only want to get one of his property (String), not the POJO itself.
When i've used autoComplete successfully it only with full POJO, I mean : use a list of POJO and on selection also get a POJO (and not only one of his property).

```
<p:autoComplete
        value="#{testBean.selectedA.val2}"
        completeMethod="#{testBean.testAutoComplete}"
        var="varB" 
        itemLabel="#{varB.val10}"
        itemValue="#{varB.val10}" 
        forceSelection="true" dropdown="true">

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{varB.val10}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{varB.val11}" />
        </p:column>

</p:autoComplete>
```

Here testBean.selectedA.val2 is of type String. In fact selectedA is a DTO, so inside all property are of primitive type, or String type, but no other POJO.
varB is a POJO
varB.val10 is of type String.
varB.val11 is of type String.

If in my backing bean testBean.selectedA.val2 is empty/null there is no problem.
Now if i need to initialize this value (testBean.selectedA.val2) in the backing bean to show a value to the user i get one error.
So i don't know how i can put a default value in the String property linked to the autoComplete

```
INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) /test.xhtml @26,42 itemLabel="#{varB.val10}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'val10'.
```

I think my problem is because i use autoComplete with POJO list but only want a String property as a result.

The problem look like this one : [Is this a bug in primefaces autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699506/is-this-a-bug-in-primefaces-autocomplete)

Do you have any ideas ?
Is it possible to use autoComplete in this conditions ?
Thank in advance for your help.

Below are some additional informations.

My configuration :
Primefaces 5.1.6
Wildfly 8.1

Full stack trace :

```
11:00:32,915 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-15) Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test.xhtml @26,42 itemLabel="#{varB.val10}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'val10'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.getItemLabel(AutoComplete.java:152) [primefaces-5.1.6.jar:5.1.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeInput(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:189) [primefaces-5.1.6.jar:5.1.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSingleMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:146) [primefaces-5.1.6.jar:5.1.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:129) [primefaces-5.1.6.jar:5.1.6]
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:107) [primefaces-5.1.6.jar:5.1.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at fr.legrain.solstyce.webapp.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'val10'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.5.Final.jar:2014-09-15 07:54]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.5.Final.jar:2014-09-15 07:54]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    ... 56 more
```

I've tried to make here a simple example to show my problem.
The view test.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">

        <p:outputLabel value="A.val1 : " />
        <p:inputText value="#{testBean.selectedA.val1}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="A.val2 : " />
        <p:autoComplete
            value="#{testBean.selectedA.val2}"
            completeMethod="#{testBean.testAutoComplete}"
            var="varB" 
            itemLabel="#{varB.val10}"
            itemValue="#{varB.val10}" 
            forceSelection="true" dropdown="true">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{varB.val10}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{varB.val11}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:autoComplete>

    </h:panelGrid>

</h:body>
</html>
```

The managed bean TestBean.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7752061447417566324L;

    private A selectedA;

    private BService bService;

    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
        bService = new BService();

        selectedA = new A();
        selectedA.setVal1("xxx");
        selectedA.setVal2("bb2"); //comment this line and there is no more problem
       }

    public List<B> testAutoComplete(String query) {
        List<B> allValues = bService.getAllValues();
        List<B> filteredValues = new ArrayList<B>();

        if(query==null || query.equals("")) {
            return allValues;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < allValues.size(); i++) {
                B b = allValues.get(i);
                if(b.getVal10().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredValues.add(b);
                }
            }
            return filteredValues;
        }
      }

    public A getSelectedA() {
        return selectedA;
    }

    public void setSelectedA(A selectedA) {
        this.selectedA = selectedA;
    }

}
```

The service BService.java :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class BService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7442506301755842723L;

    private static final List<B> allValues = new ArrayList<B>();

    public BService() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        if(allValues.isEmpty()) {
            allValues.add(new B("aa1", "ab"));
            allValues.add(new B("bb2", "abc"));
            allValues.add(new B("ab3", "abcd"));
        }
    }

    public List<B> getAllValues() {
        return allValues;
    }

}
```

The converter BConverter.java :

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;


@FacesConverter(forClass=B.class)
public class BConverter implements Converter {

    private BService bService = new BService();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object valueToRender) {
        if (valueToRender == null || valueToRender.equals("")) {  
            return "";  
        } else {  
            return String.valueOf(((B) valueToRender).getVal10());
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {  
            return null;  
        } else {  
            try {  
                //int number = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);  
                return bService.getAllValues().get(bService.getAllValues().indexOf(submittedValue));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return submittedValue;
   }

}
```

The class A.java :

```
public class A {

    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    public A() {

    }

    public A(String val1, String val2) {
        super();
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    public String getVal1() {
        return val1;
    }

    public void setVal1(String val1) {
        this.val1 = val1;
    }

    public String getVal2() {
        return val2;
    }

    public void setVal2(String val2) {
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

}
```

The class B.java :

```
public class B {

    private String val10;
    private String val11;

    public B() {

    }

    public B(String val10, String val11) {
        super();
        this.val10 = val10;
        this.val11 = val11;
    }

    public String getVal10() {
        return val10;
    }
    public void setVal10(String val10) {
        this.val10 = val10;
    }
    public String getVal11() {
        return val11;
    }
    public void setVal11(String val11) {
        this.val11 = val11;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:
`The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'val10'.` it mean that you have value of type `String` and you try to get property `val10` from this `String` which doesn't exist.

Your code has a mistake `itemValue="#{varB.val10}"` should be replaced by `itemValue="#{varB}"`, and `itemLabel="#{varB.val10}"` can be eliminated because you use:

```
   `<p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{varB.val10}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{varB.val11}" />
    </p:column>`
```

To display values. Consider rewrite your code in such way:

```
<p:autoComplete
        value="#{testBean.selectedA.val2}"
        completeMethod="#{testBean.testAutoComplete}"
        var="varB" 
        itemValue="#{varB}"
        forceSelection="true" dropdown="true">

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{varB.val10}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{varB.val11}" />
        </p:column>

</p:autoComplete>
```

And `value="#{testBean.selectedA.val2}"` should pointing to the object of same type which you get from `autocomplete` method.

Comment: In fact i've already done like this and it's working now, but i was hopping that i can avoid this solution because it need a "mapping phase" between the POJO linked to my autoComplete component and my DTO/model. Thank you anyway.